# Can i push an Activity to Background?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to push an activity to background, but the action specified in it should be done.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start a Service from the Activity. Service is the way of telling android that something needs to be run in the background. Activities are meant to be running in the foreground.
Also remember that if you have a very long task to perform, you will need to have a thread that runs in this Service.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a background thread and ends the activity whenever you want, but that thread keeps on running till it pass a message to it's handler.